# Remove text between two characters in Unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am trying to remove text between two characters ( Between space character and K)
Input string is

```
VMDJBJ 4G 15K300GB 7_34KDRV 345KUPG
```

Expected output is :

```
VMDJBJ 4G 300GB DRV UPG
```

I am using the below sed command and getting VMDJBJUPG as output.

```
echo $'VMDJBJ 4G 15K300GB 7_34KDRV 345KUPG'| sed 's/[[:space:]].*K//'
VMDJBJUPG
```

Can experts assist me here ?

Comment: Can your input contain a K in any other context where you do NOT want the chars before it removed, e.g. `15KFOOKBAR`?

Comment: No, all the cases of it should be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
echo 'VMDJBJ 4G 15K300GB 7_34KDRV 345KUPG' |
    sed -E 's/[^[:space:]]+K//g'
```

or

```
echo 'VMDJBJ 4G 15K300GB 7_34KDRV 345KUPG' |
    sed -E 's/[^[:blank:]]+K//g'
```

output :

```
VMDJBJ 4G 300GB DRV UPG
```

> `$ man gawk | grep -E '\[:blank:\]|\[:space:\]'`
>         [:blank:]  Space or tab characters.
>         [:space:]  Space characters (such as space, tab, and formfeed, to name a few).

- `[^]` means all but this *character(s) class*

Comment: Hi Gilles,Thanks for the response.The above sed command is not removing all cases ,i.e 7_34K and 345K is still present.                                                  Expected output : VMDJBJ 4G 300GB DRV UPG

Comment: I suggest: `sed -E 's/[^[:space:]]+K//g`

Comment: Added `g` modifier, fixed

Answer (score 2):

Adding an `awk` solution too here now.

```
echo 'VMDJBJ 4G 15K300GB 7_34KDRV 345KUPG' |  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/.*K/,"",$i)}} 1'
```